# website does not open in google chrome responsive mode in mac

Tags: browser

I am facing a problem when I am using Google chrome in responsive mode in mac. Whenever I open inspect element of any website in google chrome then by default it opens perfect once. After that, when i choose another width then it opens in a small corner of the page. The rest of the page converts to white color and I'm unable to use responsive mode. I attach both of image below. One is correct and second one is incorrect.

Comment: I Solved the problem, it was google chrome's bug. and after 2 days they solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in my chrome browser, after having deep research I got the solution that it was the bug in google chrome, which has been instantly solved by Google Chrome in the new version.